# Outlook UI thread is blocked when convert msg to eml using Outlook redemption

Tags: outlook-redemption

Outlook UI thread is blocked when convert msg to eml using redemption

I'm developping an outlook addin to sync emails to server as eml. When the addin start, it will start a timer and check whether there's new emails  and then upload them. For each email, I will convert them to eml using outlook Redemption. It works, but I found during the convertion, outlook UI would be blocked. I'm using following code to do the convertion. I also tried RDOSession.GetMessageFromID(mail.EntryID). It's the same. Anyone

```
public static string ToEmlFile(this Outlook.MailItem mail)
        {
            var msgFilename = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetTempFileName(), ".msg");
            mail.SaveAs(msgFilename);

            var item = RDOSessionMgr.GetInstance().GetMessageFromMsgFile(msgFilename);
            var emlFilename = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetTempFileName(), ".eml");
            item.SaveAs(emlFilename, Redemption.rdoSaveAsType.olRFC822);

            return emlFilename;
        }

 public class RDOSessionMgr
    {
        private static Redemption.RDOSession _session;

        static RDOSessionMgr()
        {
            _session = new Redemption.RDOSession();
            _session.Logon(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        }

        public static Redemption.RDOSession GetInstance()
        {
            return _session;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run that code on a secondary thread - save the value of the Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT property in a global/class variable, then assign that value to the RDOSession.MAPIOBJECT property of the RDOSession object that you create on the secondary thread.

ON a related note, you can use that technique on the main thread as well - there is no reason to RDOSession.LOgon from inside an Outlook addin since you already have the MAPI session used by Outlook.

Comment: thanks dmitry for your reply.  I'm trying to update my code as you suggested. But got another issue. When my addin startup, I try to set MAPIOBJECTInstance = this.Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT, but it seems session.MAPIOBJECT is null. Do I need to init it somewhere?

Comment: That happens because Outlook does not yet have a MAPI session at that point. Use the Application.MAPILogonComplete event. Note that you need to use both if you want to cache MAPIOBJECT on startup.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and it works, but still I'm facing the UI thread stuck issue. I found when I called  RDOMail.SaveAs(filename, Redemption.rdoSaveAsType.olRFC822), outlook UI would get stuck for a quick time and my action on outlook would postpone a bit. I'm using a timer and inside time, I used another background thread to do this, double ensure everything  is asynchronous. Do you have any idea?

Comment: For how long would the UI lock?

Comment: For each MailItem, it would lock maybe 200 million seconds.

Comment: Do you see the same problem if you specify olRfc822_Redemption format?

Comment: I solved this issue by using RdoMail.CopyTo(), then I same the new instance to eml file. Thanks any way.